# How to use Journey Exit Condition as Trigger to Execute Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there any option to make an Contact Exit from Journey a trigger to executing specific Activity (e.g. send an email for the Contact after the Contact exists Journey due to Exit Criteria)?
I looked through the documentation and couldn't find an elegant solution.

As far as I understand, there are 2 ways to achieve this behavior:

1. To place the Decision Split blocks after each Wait Activity. Thus, the paths of these Decision Splits will be the same (with 2 options: to continue and exit Journey) where the path which is equivalent to Exit Criteria will lead to the Activity and then to Exit.

The disadvantage of this solution is that Decision Splits with the same Exit path behaviour are duplicated as many times as there are Wait Flow Controls in the Journey

2. To create the second Journey and to use the Exit Criteria of the First Journey as Entry Source Criteria of the Second Journey.

The disadvantages of this solution are that

- the audience for journey (2) will not be exactly the same as contacts exited the journey (1)
- both Journeys should be running simultaneously, but can't be marked as related in User Interface (-> possible human error as one can stop the journey (2) and the behavior will be disrupted)

Could you please give advice on how is it better to implement this behavior in SFMC? (edited)

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially look at using the undocumented /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search REST API route in conjuntion with scripting from an Automation Studio program. @Gortonington did a nice job of setting out how to do this a few years ago in his blog post [Journey History for Last 30 Days via API](https://gortonington.com/journey-history-for-last-30-days-via-api/). Alternatively, you could build something outside of SFMC using the documented [Journey History Download route](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_interaction/downloadJourneyHistory.html).

Although undocumented, for the first option you can play around with the API in the history tab of Journey Builder to reverse engineer the various parameters you can use to refine your search to retrieve just the events you're interested in. For your use case, you're interested in just retrieving Exit Criteria events where the contact met the exit criteria for one or more Journey Versions.

**Sample Request:**

POST: {{restEndpoint}}interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$page=1&$pageSize=1000

```json
{
    "definitionIds": [
        "5b685bba-6185-4e62-b2b3-b040dfd4e920",
        "2331d36d-4dca-4e48-b4b4-e411d1c601b7"
    ],
    "activityTypes": [
        "exitcriteriaactivity"
    ],
    "statuses": [
        "exitcriteriamet"
    ],
    "end": null,
    "start": "2023-11-12T08:00:00.000Z"
}
```

**Sample Response:**

```json
{
    "count": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 1000,
    "links": {},
    "items": [{
            "id": "499189730",
            "longId": 499189730,
            "mid": 123456789,
            "eventId": "707e9d5f-c162-4e11-b0c6-71f484976dac",
            "definitionId": "5b685bba-6185-4e62-b2b3-b040dfd4e920",
            "definitionName": "My Journey",
            "eventName": "My Journey",
            "contactKey": "abc123456789",
            "entrySource": "SourceQueueSlotWorker.ProcessItem",
            "epochTimeInMilliseconds": 1699826521648,
            "transactionTime": "2023-11-12T22:02:01.648Z",
            "status": "ExitCriteriaMet",
            "clientStatus": "Success",
            "message": "",
            "activityId": "097526eb-da79-49be-81a3-b426ef32c1d8",
            "activityType": "ExitCriteriaActivity",
            "activityName": "",
            "definitionInstanceId": "5c8cc799-e4d0-46f0-9a76-e706e5acb530",
            "createdDate": "2023-11-12T16:02:01.648-06:00",
            "activityBatchInstanceId": "f952bec7-685c-45b0-99d4-a4818edc64c7",
            "eid": 987654321,
            "startDate": "2023-11-12T16:02:01.414-06:00",
            "endDate": "2023-11-12T16:02:01.648-06:00",
            "outcomeActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "sourceType": 0,
            "_score": 0.0,
            "messageSource": 1
        }]
}
```

So, your SSJS script would need a little sophistication added, like first getting the array of definitionIds you're interested in, so you don't need to update your script each time you re-version your journey. The route of interest here is [/interaction/v1/interactions/{id}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_interaction/getInteractionById.html). You'll also need to implement paging through multiple pages of Exit Criteria Events and guard against timeouts.

Finally, you can look at the [/interaction/v1/events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_interaction/postEvent.html) endpoint to insert those exiting from your journey into another journey.